# measure running time of c code with windows commandline

Tags: c, windows, gcc

I write a program in C with gcc. I want to measure the running time of my code when before it produces a result.
I used time in my command:

```
time ./failname
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: best way to check run-time of programs is to embed the time calculation within the crogram try using <time.h> or supporting alternative for the platform.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execution time of C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248915/execution-time-of-c-program)

Comment: What exactly did you expect to happen as the result of your command?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27262773/1983398).